# JUnit Code generation - compatible to java 1.4

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, eclipse-plugin, junit3

My project is developed in `java 1.4` .I need to generate junit codes. While I google-ed a bit on this, I can see **all the code-generators are junit 4** compliant (annotation based mostly) and junit 4 is compiled in `java 1.5`

The best thing would be to use is only `junit-3`, But wondering **is there any opensource code-generator compliant to junit-3 ?** Please suggest me on this

Comment: Don't generate unit test, write them.

Comment: we have 200 java files. Since there are already generators for junit, we just want to use that ... Just a basic structure for every class is fine, we would quickly write the test logic within the method.

Comment: You can use Eclipse for a "basic structure". Don't generate unit tests.

Comment: To echo other comments - don't generate unit tests. A good approach for this is to introduce a policy where 'if you are going to change a file without unit tests, then you have to write unit tests for it first'. This will allow you to focus your efforts on getting tests in place where you need them, and allow you to fit it alongside your project work without requiring a single, concerted effort to retrofit an entire test suite (which will also likely lead to poor quality tests, especially if using a test code generator).

Comment: You guys really dont seem to understand at all. Thanks for ur advices. At the same time, the project which am currently in, is 8 years old project and all of a sudden they want junit to be part of it. It has more than 250 java files for which I cannot write junit rather I am seeking help of a tool which would do it behalf of me and later I can quickly review the generated code !!

Answer (score 0):

I found a tool which is fulling the requirement.

It is [CodePro](https://developers.google.com/java-dev-tools/codepro/doc/) !!

There we have option which will decide whether the code to be generated based on Junit-3 or Junit-4.

Found it finally :-)